# How to set port 44400 as default in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

My website work only if I run:

> domain.com:44400

How to set port 44400 as default in Apache?

I need have access by `domain.com` not `domain.com:44400`

Comment: That's not how http or apache works, `http://<whatever>` means port 80. You could however change ports with a firewall in front of the server.

Comment: That question is unclear. Apache, by default, will bind to port 80 (default for HTTP). If it only works on port 44400 then it means you either have changed the configuration yourself or you're not explaining what you've done and what setup your running (NAT firewall, reverse proxy, custom application stack, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could configure Apache to listen on port 80, and proxy to port 44400:

Add the following to your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file (assuming you already have port 44400 configured):

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Then create a proxy virtual host in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com-proxy.conf` (minimal configuration shown, YMMV):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass        / http://domain.com:44400/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com:44400/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com_proxy_error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com_proxy_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And symlink to `sites-enabled`:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com-proxy.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com-proxy.conf
```

Enable proxy modules and restart Apache:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use firewall (iptables) to redirect all traffic have destination port 80 to port 44400. Something like this

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s any/0 -d X.X.X.X --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 44400
```

Then you can access your website by typing in browser

> http://yourdomain.com